# NMinimize violates constraints

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value

I have a rather convoluted objective function to minimize, subject to some constraints. The results violates the constraints. The following example highlights the issue:

```
ObjectFunc = 1 - 0.000911933 s1 - 0.000911933 s2 - 0.000911933 s3;
Mat = {{1. - 0.0027358 s1, 0. + 0.0192484 s1, 0. + 0.022066 s1}, {0. + 0.0192484 s1, 1. - 0.135427 s1 - 0.138162 s2, 0. - 0.15525 s1 - 0.111996 s2}, {0. + 0.022066 s1, 0. - 0.15525 s1 - 0.111996 s2, 1 - 0.177976 s1 - 0.090786 s2 - 0.0198013 s3}};

NMinimize[{ObjectFunc, Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0}, {s1, s2, s3}]
```

Specifically, if I evaluate `Det[Mat]` with the optimised parameters, I get a negative number. Admittedly, it is a very small negative number, but negative nonetheless. I have looked at changing the `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`.

Any ideas why `NMinimize` fails to appropriately constrain the objective function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not expect high precision results using machine precision numbers.

Start by converting all values to exact numbers.

```
ObjectFunc = 
  1 - 0.000911933 s1 - 0.000911933 s2 - 0.000911933 s3 // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;

Mat = {{1. - 0.0027358 s1, 0. + 0.0192484 s1, 
      0. + 0.022066 s1}, {0. + 0.0192484 s1, 1. - 0.135427 s1 - 0.138162 s2, 
      0. - 0.15525 s1 - 0.111996 s2}, {0. + 0.022066 s1, 
      0. - 0.15525 s1 - 0.111996 s2, 
      1 - 0.177976 s1 - 0.090786 s2 - 0.0198013 s3}} // Rationalize[#, 0] & //
    Simplify;
```

Unfortunately, there is no solution that satisfies the constraints.

```
({min, arg} = 
  Minimize[{ObjectFunc, Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0}, {s1, s2, 
    s3}])

(* Minimize::natt: The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.

{-∞, {s1 -> Indeterminate, s2 -> Indeterminate, 
  s3 -> Indeterminate}} *)
```

Consequently, the closest you can get is an approximate numeric solution on the boundary of the constrained region.

```
({min, arg} = 
   NMinimize[{ObjectFunc, Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0}, {s1, 
     s2, s3}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]) // N

(* {0.953946, {s1 -> 0., s2 -> 0., s3 -> 50.5017}} *)

Det[Mat] /. arg // N

(* -5.91946*10^-25 *)
```

Increasing the `WorkingPrecision` will bring the `Det` closer to zero.

```
({min, arg} = 
   NMinimize[{ObjectFunc, Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0}, {s1, 
     s2, s3}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]) // N

(* {0.953946, {s1 -> 0., s2 -> 0., s3 -> 50.5017}} *)

(Det[Mat] /. arg) // N

(* -1.26523*10^-49 *)
```

Comment: Sorry @Bob Hanlon , this is not a problem of solution at boundaries, but the fact, that NMinimize simply finds a local minimum. As Minimize says, minimum is at - Infinity with si -> Infinity. Constraints give two distinct 3 dim regions, as log-Plot of it shows. Nminimize gets catched in the small region at si near zero. See `rp = RegionPlot3D[
   red /. {s1 -> Exp[ls1] - 1, s2 -> Exp[ls2] - 1, 
     s3 -> Exp[ls3] - 1}, {ls1, 0, 15}, {ls2, 0, 15}, {ls3, 0, 15}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Yellow], 
   Mesh -> False]; `   and see next comment.

Comment: `of[ls1_, ls2_, ls3_] = 
 ObjectFunc /. {s1 -> Exp[ls1] - 1, s2 -> Exp[ls2] - 1, 
   s3 -> Exp[ls3] - 1}; cp = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  of[ls1, ls2, ls3], {ls1, 0, 20}, {ls2, 0, 20}, {ls3, 0, 20}, 
  Contours -> {0.953946, -20, -2000}, ContourStyle -> Blue]; ` `Show[rp, cp] `

Comment: `red = Reduce[
   Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0, {s1, s2, s3}]; `

Answer (score 2):

First, let us convert decimals to rationals.

```
ObjectFunc = Rationalize[1 - 0.000911933 s1 - 0.000911933 s2 - 0.000911933 s3,10^-20];
Mat = Rationalize[{{1. - 0.0027358 s1, 0. + 0.0192484 s1, 
0. + 0.022066 s1}, {0. + 0.0192484 s1, 
1. - 0.135427 s1 - 0.138162 s2, 
0. - 0.15525 s1 - 0.111996 s2}, {0. + 0.022066 s1, 
0. - 0.15525 s1 - 0.111996 s2, 
1 - 0.177976 s1 - 0.090786 s2 - 0.0198013 s3}}, 10^-20]
```

Second, let us find the exact solution of the problem under consideration.

```
Minimize[{ObjectFunc,Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && s3 > 0}, {s1, s2, s3}]
```

> Minimize::natt: The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.

```
(*{-\[Infinity], {s1 -> Indeterminate, s2 -> Indeterminate, s3 -> Indeterminate}}*)
```

Indeed,

```
FindInstance[ObjectFunc == -1000 && Det[Mat] > 0 && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0 && 
s3 > 0, {s1, s2, s3}, Reals]
(*{{s1 -> 90996849686/82903, s2 -> 1, s3 -> 37}}*)
```