# Equality contraint violated with NMinimize

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, numerics, numerical-value

I am attempting to numerically optimize a function of only 2 parameters `k, θ`. There are two inequality constraints (1 each on `k` and on `θ`), and one equality constraint on both `k and θ`. The *MWE* is provided below. This question is a follow-on from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276818/nminimize-keeps-returning-indeterminate-for-well-defined-function/276823#276823) that was answered by @user293787. I have seen a [related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235152/nminimize-violates-constraints), but the solution did not work here.

I have noticed that the `Minimize` performs well when only the two inequality constraints are included. However, I get a warning when I include the equality constraint, which is always violated.

How can I get around this?

**MWE:**

```
s[x_]:=Total[x*Log2[x]];

A=DiagonalMatrix[{0.0632,0.3065,0.0632,0.3065}];
B=DiagonalMatrix[{0.3065,0.0632,0.3065,0.0632}];
AB=MatrixPower[A.A+B.B,1/2];

f[k_?NumericQ,θ_?NumericQ]:=With[{T={
   {2 k Cos[θ]^2+k+1,0,0,6 k Cos[θ]^2-k-1},
   {0,2 k Sin[θ]^2+3-3 k,0,0},
   {0,0,2 k Sin[θ]^2+3-3 k,0},
   {6 k Cos[θ]^2-k-1,0,0,2 k Cos[θ]^2+k+1}}},
      s[Eigenvalues[AB.T.AB]]-s[Eigenvalues[A.T.A]]-s[Eigenvalues[B.T.B]]
];
```

I would like to optimise `f[k,θ]` using the following

```
x1 = 0 <= k <= 1;
x2 = 0 < θ <= 2 \[Pi];
x3 = 3 - (2 k - 3) - k Cos[2 θ] == 0;

{min, arg} = NMinimize[{f[k,θ], x1 && x2 && x3}, {k, θ}]
```

The output to this `NMinimize` yields outputs a result with a comments `"The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {k,θ} = {1,6.2831}"`. However, despite an output when I check the constraints I notice that the equality constraint is always violated and by a lot, i.e.

```
x3 /. arg
```

yields `False`. In checking the value of x3 using the optimization values in `arg`, I obtain 3 (should be 0), which is a strong violation of the constraint. If I remove the equality constraint `x3` I notice that the optimization behaves properly. `Rationalising` `A` and `B` does not help.

What is the cause of this and a workaround to enforce the equality constraint?

Comment: Is it clear that plugging a floating-point solution into an equation is a bad way to check it?  E.g. `x^2 - 3 == 0 /. x -> Sqrt[3.]` returns `False`. (Apparently not the main problem here, tho.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, in a convoluted way you could use `Chop` to check this statement, is correct with floating-point solutions. As you note though, it's not the main problem here. I may need to revisit the constraints

Answer (score 4):

```
Reduce[x1 && x2 && x3, {k, \[Theta]}]
(* False*)
```

The three conditions cannot be fullfilled!
Perhaps changing range of k might help.